# Arduino Uno R3 USB is not working

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, linux

I have a problem with my Arduino Uno board. It's not mounting in my Linux machine, but its power is *on* and the LED light is glowing. It was working before. After I tested buttons with an 12 V external supply, I am facing this scenario.

I tried `lsusb` and I checked `/dev/ ports`. Also, I couldn't find `ttyACM. I tried with another Arduino board and it's working. I think the board is gone, and I need help to fix this problem.

I thought it was a bootloader problem, and I got a *new ATmega328P chip board*. It is getting power on and the LED is blinking, but the port is not mounted. I tried with `lsusb` and also `ls /dev/ttyACM*` with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to flash the firmware of the USB controller.

General steps for Arduino R3 are:

1. Put the Arduino in DFU mode (the R3 does *not* require soldering for that)
2. Flash the firmware using:

   ```
   dfu-programmer atmega16u2 erase
   dfu-programmer atmega16u2 flash Arduino-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex
   dfu-programmer atmega16u2 reset
   ```

   The package "dfu-programmer" is most likely available for your distribution.

If you have to build it from source, because your DFU programmer does not know the ATmega16U2 yet, you will need to install libusb-dev (on Debian-based systems).

Useful links for that:

- *[Resetting your Uno R3's default firmware](https://github.com/leocadiotine/Dvorany/wiki/Resetting-your-Uno-R3%27s-default-firmware)*
- *[Updating the Atmega8U2 and 16U2 on an Uno or Mega2560 using DFU](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2)*

A useful search term for that is `Arduino R3 DFU-programmer`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to "reflash" the FTDI firmware. Sorry, I'm very bad in Linux. To do this, you'll need some software and a HEX file. Check this video on YouTube:

*[ARDUINO- Upgrading USB FIRMWARE using FLIP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSXZMVdO5Sg)*

And download the *arduino_usbtoserial.hex* file.

If it doesn't work, and if your Arduino Uno has the ATmega328P chip as [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package), try to change the ATmega328P chip in the board. Remove this chip carefully. Put another chip in with the bootloader and test.